# How does telegram shows the Icon of some websites?

Tags: html, css, metadata, telegram

I am working with telegram on windows and its online version on web.telegram.org, when I share a link with my friend Telegram shows the icon or logo of some websites in that message:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvzzY.png)

The first website is *vajehyab.com* and it has a **favicon** too (But do not showing that website icon), and the second is Stackoverflow and as you see the logo of stackoverflow and a litle description shows beside it.

Does websites do something or having some metadata that allow Telegram to access their logo, or it is an static program form Telegram programmers and the set some famous websites logo?

Comment: You can learn about the related technology: http://ogp.me/ OpenGraph

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Just add these tags to your website

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Title" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Site name"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="Description" />
<meta property="og:image" content="Link to your logo" />
```

Comment: I added these tags but my website is still not shown in preview. How do you set the link to logo?

Comment: You should add something like `<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.example.com/images/logo.png" />` and it usually takes sometime for bots to search your website again for changes in open graphs.

Comment: you can update the preview with telegrams WebpageBot instantly

Comment: it doesn't seem to work with favicon.ico images. Does image format matter?

Comment: According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/, only jpeg, gif or png are supported.

Answer (score 13):

As well as adding what @Manikiran proposed you need to add this

```
<html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
```

and use telegrams @WebpageBot afterwards