# what does telegram look for in order to grab url info?

Tags: web, telegram, audio-player

when you send a URL to your friends in telegram it tries to view info about the URL and even shows a player if it refers to media.

I have a music player page in my website,i like to view a music player in telegram when someone sends the URL of my page to others rather than just viewing a URL.

Youtube does that with videos.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does telegram shows the Icon of some websites?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30160294/how-does-telegram-shows-the-icon-of-some-websites)

Comment: that was very helpfull, thanks. but what about playing music?

Comment: You must use open graph protocol
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31376378/what-should-be-structure-of-website-to-retrieve-site-information-in-telegram